# Symfony router redirect to http on a https application

Tags: symfony, http, routes

I'm migrating my application from `https://mywebsite.com` (**1**) to `https://otherwebsite.com` (**2**)
The application is host on a different servers

The code bellow work well on (**1**), the scheme of the generated url is `https`. 
The same code on (**2**) generate an url with `http` scheme

```
$filterUrl = $this->router->generate('liip_imagine_filter', $params, UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL);
```

The route definition is

```
<route id="liip_imagine_filter" path="/media/cache/resolve/{filter}/{path}" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">%liip_imagine.controller.filter_action%</default>
        <requirement key="filter">[A-z0-9_\-]*</requirement>
        <requirement key="path">.+</requirement>
</route>
```

Classic use of the Symfony router, have you got any ideas why on (**1**) I got `https` and on (**2**) I got `http` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are not passing `schemes` and `host` attributes to the route `liip_imagine_filter`, UrlGenerator uses current request's ones.

The issue is that PHP receives request information from web server and sometimes it gets not what you expect. There might be some kind of reverse-proxy such as Nginx that accepts HTTPS requests from Internet and forward them to another Nginx by HTTP, in the end symfony receives HTTP scheme.

To find out if the (2) server behind reverse-proxy create `test.php` file with:

```
<?php

echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'];
```

It will output current request scheme.

For setting up Symfony to work under reversed proxy read this article from the official documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment/proxies.html